# Corel draw 13 mysql query

Tags: mysql, coreldraw

Is there a way to do a mysql database query in Corel Draw 13(X3)?

Comment: Why do you want to do a database query in a drawing program? Are you writing a plugin?

Comment: Interesting. We may need a new question tag: EverythingYouAlwaysWantedtoKnowAboutCorelDrawButWereAfraidtoAsk :)

Comment: JS Bangs: I am integrating a database of prices with a catalog of prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, CorelDraw uses VBA as scripting language, no?

If so, if it is not restricted, you can probably use ODBC to do that. See [MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up PhiLho's point, [here's a Google-scanned book that shows using ODBC to connect to an MS-Access database](http://books.google.ca/books?id=9OTV1YNLLBsC&pg=PT609&lpg=PT609&dq=Corel+draw+odbc&source=web&ots=2CEhpBo-cE&sig=FjIShZtwQmdSnYMlEtyrEzkR5ys&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result#PPT611,M1)